# JQuery: attach the same callback to one or more elements

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I have to prevent user to insert letters in numeric fields.
I use this:

```
 $('input[name=myinput]').live('keyup', function() {
                var $th = $(this);
                $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^0-9,\.]/g, ''));
        });
```

How could I list the other input fields? (I can't use $('input'))

I tried with

```
$('input[name=myinput],input[name=myinput2]').live('keyup', function() {
                var $th = $(this);
                $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^0-9,\.]/g, ''));
        });
```

but only input[name=myinput] is accepted.

Comment: Nope, you're mistaken

Comment: Ops... You're right, the name of the input field is another. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a class on the input element and then do:

```
$('input.eKeyup').live('keyup', function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^0-9,\.]/g, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Group them in a css class and use `$('.className')` it's faster and easier.